# 502 Bad Gateway with nginx connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream with Blazor WASM and nginx reverse proxy with SSL

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose

I'm new to docker. Learning and practicing it. I'm trying to connect to my `blazor wasm` app via `nginx` reverse proxy but getting the below error.

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xx.xxx.x, server: www-local.test.com, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://xxx.xx.x.x:5005/index.html", host: "www-local.test.com:44395"
```

Here is my project Structure:

```
-Solution.sln
|-docker-compose.yml
|-nginx (reverse-proxy)
  |-nginx.Dockerfile
  |-nginx.local.conf
  |-www-local.crt
  |-www-local.key
|-Web (blazor wasm)
  |-Docker
  |-nginx.conf
  |-Web.csproj
```

Here is my configuration:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  reverseproxy:
    image: blazorstandalone-reverseproxy
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx/nginx.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - blazorstandalone
    ports:
      - "44395:44395"
    networks:
      blazornet:
        aliases:
          - "www-local.test.com"

  blazorstandalone:
    image: blazorstandalone
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Web/Docker
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - blazornet

networks:
  blazornet: {}
```

`nginx.Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx/nginx.local.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx/www-local.crt /etc/ssl/certs/www-local.test.com.crt
COPY nginx/www-local.key /etc/ssl/private/www-local.test.com.key
```

`nginx.local.conf`:

```
worker_processes 1;
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

    upstream ui {
        server blazorstandalone:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 44395 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/www-local.test.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/www-local.test.com.key;

        server_name www-local.test.com;   
        
        location / {
             proxy_pass         http://ui;
             proxy_redirect     off;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
             proxy_set_header   Host $host:44395;
             proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
             proxy_buffer_size           128k;
             proxy_buffers               4 256k;
             proxy_busy_buffers_size     256k;
        }
    }
}
```

Blazor project `docker` file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-alpine AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output

FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/web
COPY --from=build-env /app/output/wwwroot .
COPY Web/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

Blazor project `nginx.conf`:

```
events { }
   http {
      include mime.types;
      types {
         application/wasm;
       }
     server {
        listen 80;
        index index.html;
        location / {
           root /var/www/web;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
     }
}
```

When I run `docker compose up`, I can see both containers are running and I can see all the files inside `blazorstandalone` container and inside `blazorstandalone-reverseproxy` container.

I have added HOST file entry.

`127.0.0.1 www-local.test.com`

Now when I try to access via `https://www-local.test.com:44395/index.html`, I get `502 Bad Gateway Error`.

[image]

But it still runs in `http://localhost:8080`

[image]

Please anyone assist me on where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some hours I have finally found it.

It's the issue with port mapping. The port number in `upstream` should be `container` port `80` instead of `host` port `8080`.

`nginx.local.conf`

```
upstream ui {
    server blazorstandalone:80;
}
```